# I need to replace the bathroom water lines under the vanity, but the line at the sink ends have no fittings. Faucets have screw in horizontal handles

Tags: vanity

How do I replace bathroom water lines that have no fittings at the bottom of the sink faucets Faucets have removal handles that have a long horizontal screw that doesn't seem to hold anything. Seems to me that I may need to remove the entire sink. Never saw anything
like this. In a modern older home.

Comment: We cannot see what you see. Please take a pic (or several), and attach to your question by using the "Edit" button below the question, and then the "Moon & Mountains" button that appears over the text entry box.

Comment: If you're referring to the flexible braided water supply lines being permanently attached to the faucet assembly, I've started to see that in the last decade or so. It seems to be a cost-saving (and installation effort saving) measure by the faucet manufacturers, but AFAIK it also means you need to replace the whole faucet if the supply lines become defective.

Comment: As it stands without picture, unscrew the faucet and. the water line from under the sink and pull it up.